# Prove every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is either finite or countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove every infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is either finite or countable. I think I have defined the function correctly, however I am having trouble showing the function is injective and surjective.

Suppose $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ is infinite. Define a function $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$. Let $f(1)=\text{min}\{n \in \mathbb{N}| n \in A \}$. Assume $f(n)$ has been defined for all $k<n$. Choose $f(n)=\text{min}\{n \in \mathbb{N}|n \in A-\{f(1),...,f(n-1)\}\}$. Then $f$ is a bijective function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$. $f$ is one to one since if $m \neq n$ and $m<n$ then $f(n) \in \{A-\{f(1),...,f(n-1)\}\}$ however $f(m) \in \{f(1),...,f(n-1)\}$. $f$ is onto since if $a \in A$, $a=f(n)\in \text{min}\{n \in \mathbb{N}|n \in A-\{f(1),...,f(n-1)\}\}$ after inductively taking out the minimum element.

I would like to know how I could better show that the defined function is one to one and onto. Also, do I need to even worry about the finite case? I know to prove a statement of the form $p \implies (q \ \vee r)$ you can prove $(p \ \wedge \sim  q) \implies r$

So I felt I could disregard the finite case by using this logical equivalence.

Comment: To address the logical query: What you have is okay, by only considering the infinite case.